# Dates shown on plot x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dataformat

I am working a dataset that is quite big. It's a file that has 8 columns `(y1-y8)` with number data (e.g. 21.3456) and 1 column `(x)` with date data `(format: m/d/Y)`.

I want to contrast the 8 columns over time and a plot diagram seemed the best option for that.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_excel('Masterfile_allSTW.xlsx', 'Sheet1')

#data
#df.TS_TIMESTAMP = df.TS_TIMESTAMP.astype(str)
x = df['dates']
y1 = df['Rtemp_EG']
y2 = df['Rtemp_EG+1.OG']
y3 = df['Rtemp_1.OG']
y4 = df['Rtemp_2.OG']
y5 = df['Rtemp_3.OG']
y6 = df['Rtemp_4.OG']
y7 = df['Rtemp_5.OG']
y8 = df['Rtemp_6.OG']

#plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df.plot(ax=ax)

#set ticks every week
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
#set major ticks format
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m %d'))
```

Running the script the plot looks like this:

[image]

I am quite satisfied with the look of the plot diagram, the only thing that is missing are the date descriptions on the `x` axis (which should come from the columns `('dates')`. I have a feeling the problem lies within the `df.plot(ax=ax)` line, but I'm not sure.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is the dates a column or the index? What's the dtype of the dates? Which version of pandas and matplotlib are in use?

Comment: No, the 'dates' column is the first column after the index and the dtype is datetime64[ns]. I'm not sure which version of pandas and matplotlib I am using - how can I find out? But I'm using Python 3.7.0. on the Jupyter Notebook if this is useful information.

Comment: Does the answer below help in any way? Usually find out versions via `print(matplotlib.__version__)`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem is with `df.plot(ax=ax)`. Try replacing it with`df.plot(x='dates')` to plot against a single specific column.

Comment: Thank you!, Now I there are dates visible on the x-axis, however not in the format that I would like and formulated. ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m %d'))

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer does not help here, I would suggest making the dates column the index for plotting. There seem to be problems if the dates are a column in some cases, but I haven't understood the mechanism of why that would be the case.

```
df.set_index("dates").plot(ax=ax, x_compat=True)
```